# empty output of mongodump

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I have app running against local mongo on server with ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xx. I would like to dump data using mongodump. I ssh to the server. First i checked if mongo is running are data are there. I did `mongo` and `show dbs`, I see list of dbs. Now I did `use app` and `show collections` data are there. So I tried `mongodump --db app` and I see in console

```
connected to: 127.0.0.1
2021-10-28T11:12:03.321+0000 DATABASE: app   to     dump/app
```

Great, but only thing it did, it created dump/app folder. But folder is unfortunately empty. What I do wrong?

Comment: That's strange. If you run `mongo` and `mongodump` from the same location (so they talk to the same server), mongodump should see the same data.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yeah i know it is strange. But have no idea what is the source of this. I run from same location, mongo sees the data, mongodump only creates directory ( so it cant be write permission problem right?) but it is empty.